# RuntimeError: Event loop stopped before Future completed. Python

Tags: python, python-asyncio

So I am trying to make a minecraft name sniper, but it  throws me this error:

```
RuntimeError: Event loop stopped before Future completed.
```

My code:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
tokenlist = ['token1','token2','token3','token4','token5']
name = 'bruh'

async def send_requests():
    coros = [
            snipe_req(token) for token in tokenlist for x in range(3)

            ]
    await asyncio.wait(coros)

async def snipe_req(token):
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession().put(f"https://api.minecraftservices.com/minecraft/profile/name/{name}",headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + token,"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0","Content-Type": "application/json"}) as response:
        await response.read()
        print(response)
        asyncio.get_event_loop().stop()

def run():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    loop.run_until_complete(send_requests())

run()
```

Does anyone know where the issue here is?

Comment: why `asyncio.get_event_loop().stop()`? you are stopping the event loop with that

Answer (score 0):

you have to open session first and then use put method.

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

tokenlist = ['token1','token2','token3','token4','token5']
name = 'bruh'

async def send_requests():
    coros = [
            snipe_req(token) for token in tokenlist for x in range(3)

            ]
    await asyncio.wait(coros)

async def snipe_req(token):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
        session = await client.put(
        f"https://api.minecraftservices.com/minecraft/profile/name/{name}",
        headers={
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
            })
        await session.read()
        print(session)

def run():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(send_requests())

run()
```